# Product Matching problem in pattern matching

Tags: algorithms

The **Product Matching** problem is defined as follows: 
**Input**: Text T=t<sub>0</sub>,...,t<sub>n</sub> and pattern P=p<sub>0</sub>,...,p<sub>m</sub> over alphabet Σ=N .

**Output** : All of the i places in the text where exists c<sub>i</sub> which holds
t<sub>i+j</sub> = c<sub>i</sub> * p<sub>j</sub> for every j=0,...,m

For example: 
**T**= 2,3,9,12,1,8 **P** = 1,3,4
so in index 1 there is a match for c<sub>i</sub>=3 because:
1*3 = 3 , 3*3=9, 4*3=12

I've only managed to think about the naive way of multiplying the pattern for each number that gives
us less or equal value to max{T} and then checking it with a regular O(N) pattern matching algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Starting with the original text, form a sequence $s_1,\ldots,s_n$ by the rule $s_i = t_i/t_{t-1}$, and similarly from the original pattern form a sequence $q_1,\ldots,q_m$ by the rule $q_j = p_j/p_{j-1}$. Look for the pattern $q$ inside the text $s$.